# Is there any way to disable adding of chips(primeng) but should be deletable in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

Hi i am trying to make the chips input ineditable.I am taking the data of objects from one of the components and using the key of the data to be out as chips label.

This is my html code

```
<div class="inputDiv" *ngFor="let k of key">
  <div class="inlineclass">
      <span class="title">{{k}}</span>
          <p-chips [(ngModel)]="filterInput[k]" ></p-chips>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my component from where i am taking my data

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'itc-upc-itc-component-filter',
templateUrl: './itc-component-filter.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./itc-component-filter.component.scss']
})
export class ItcComponentFilterComponent implements OnInit {
filterInput= { 'size': ['1T', '2T', '3T'], 'status': [ 'in progress','complete', 'pending']};
key= Object.keys(this.filterInput);
constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
}

}
```

I have tried disabled property of ng primes chips property

```
<p-chips [(ngModel)]="filterInput[k]" disabled="true"></p-chips>
```

Is there any way that i can make this input uneditable but at the same time should be able to delete the chip

Comment: @vega what does that mean??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should listen to the keyboard events where only `backspace` and `delete` keys should be allowed. That way you can remove but not add characters.

**HTML:**

```
  <span *ngIf="filterInput[k]" class="title">{{k}}</span>
  <p-chips (keydown)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="filterInput[k]" ></p-chips>
```

**Typescript**

```
   onChange(event){
       if (!(event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46)){
           return false
       }

   }
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/TsV0WaWx7S9Ak1D7P2CH?p=preview)

Comment: in the above as u can see i am printing k value value infront of the chips..Is there any way if i delete all the chips the k value should also
disappear

Comment: with an *ngIf where you check if the filterInput[k] value is empty

Comment: not working ..i have tried this *ngIf="_filterInput?.length > 0".But this is making the k dissapear and then i am getting chips as per the loop

Comment: Not working : 1. it still displays 2. error in the log ?

Comment: it still displays

Comment: I re-read your question. You are asking to remove {{k}} display when ALL the chips are deleted or the current ? What's wrong with your above solution ? just remove _ before filterInput

Comment: firstly i need to get k along with chips ...then when i delete all the chips then i should not k .But in my case k is not being displayed even before i delete any chips

Comment: Try filter with *ngIf= "filterInput" or *ngIf="filterInput.length". If it doesn't work could you change the demo to the situation adn I will try to correct?

Answer (score 0):

Angular + Lodash

```
 <p-chips [(ngModel)]="chips" (keydown)="onChangeChips($event)"></p-chips>
```

```
import {BACKSPACE, DELETE} from '@angular/cdk/keycodes';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

onChangeChips(event) {
  return _.has([BACKSPACE, DELETE], event.code);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<p-chips [(ngModel)]="filterInput[k]" [inputStyle]="{ display: 'none' }"></p-chips>
```